# link to list in "View Site content" is corrupt

Tags: 2013, list

I have recently done a restore on a site that was backed up from another server
(sp2013 onpremise)

When I go to mysite/viewlsts.aspx and click on one of my document libraries, it links to mysites/listname and not mysites/listname/forms/AllItems.aspx as expected. This leads to a "page not found"-page. However if I input the correct url in the address bar Everything works fine.

[image]

Its just this list, all other list's links looks fine. I can go to the list settings without any problems.

Is there anyway to re-set this lists link to the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot

Open list settings and try setting the default view to AllItems. Or create a new view and set it as the default view.

Comment: That was it.I had no view at all on that list...Thanks!!!